# Ploting a function with a specific formula

Tags: matlab

Does any one know how can I plot:

```
 ln(y/20)*(1+2.98e10*y)=-x/10e-12
```

I want to plot `y` versus `x` in matlab.
And Also obtain x, and y values??
Thank you for your help

Comment: same here :), f you liked my answer, mark it as good. It will help any future people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ezplot](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/ezplot.html)

Do:

```
ezplot('log(y./20)*(1+2.98e10*y)+x./10e-12',[xmin xmax ymin ymax])
```

from [-1 1 -1 1] you'll get

[image]

Comment: How I can obtain the values of x and y??? I tried to obtain know , but I did not be successful:(

Comment: x=-ln(y/20)*(1+2.98e10*y)*10e-12. Just give Y some values (i.e. y=-1:0.01:1 and get x...